# Generate `Objects.requireNonNull` lines for each argument automatically in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, parameter-passing, auto-generate, notnull

Might there be a way in IntelliJ 2018 to auto-generate the lines of code checking for null values passed in any argument?

I want IntelliJ to change this:

```
// ----------|  Constructor  |-----------------------------------
public DailyProduct ( LocalDate localDate , String name , Integer quantity ) {
    this.localDate = localDate;
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

…to this:

```
// ----------|  Constructor  |-----------------------------------
public DailyProduct ( LocalDate localDate , String name , Integer quantity , BigDecimal quality , BigDecimal realmq , BigDecimal cost ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull( localDate );  // ⬅ Generate these checks for null values.
    Objects.requireNonNull( name );
    Objects.requireNonNull( quantity );

    this.localDate = localDate;
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

Even better would be if IntelliJ could write all the argument-to-member assignments *and* use the `Objects.requireNonNull`. So this:

```
// ----------|  Constructor  |-----------------------------------
public DailyProduct ( LocalDate localDate , String name , Integer quantity , BigDecimal quality , BigDecimal realmq , BigDecimal cost ) {
}
```

…would become this:

```
// ----------|  Constructor  |-----------------------------------
public DailyProduct ( LocalDate localDate , String name , Integer quantity ) {
    this.localDate = Objects.requireNonNull( localDate );  // ⬅ Generate all these lines entirely.
    this.name = Objects.requireNonNull( name );
    this.quantity = Objects.requireNonNull( quantity );
}
```

Comment: You can create a [Live Template](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) to do that.

Comment: Do you have a good reason not to want to use the return value? `this.localDate = Objects.requireNonNull(localDate);`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh, yes, even better. I never noticed that return value. Thanks! Editing the Question now to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

You could try the following:

In Settings / Live template create a new live template

[image]

define the $content$ variable with [Edit Variables]:

[image]

with the following groovyScript:

> groovyScript("def params = _1.collect { 'this.' + it + ' = Objects.requireNonNull(' + it + ');' }.join(); params", methodParameters());

now when you use the abbreviation

[image]

you should get the following

[image]

Let me know if it helps.